# Does the Heston calibration have to be done on an arbitrage-free surface?

Tags: stochastic-volatility, heston, volatility-surface

In a similar way to local volatility? 
I'm trying to calibrate a surface, but the results aren't convincing, so I was wondering if it was necessary to first use a way to regulate it (splines, regressions), then calibrate the Heston model, or if it was necessary to calibrate first the model on the few data, then get a surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your heston model parameters should define the surface. You're fitting to options quoted in the market, thus a minimization exercise.
Not like local vol, where it needs a abitrage free implied vol surface to garantee uniqueness

Comment: Thank  you ! I should do better then.